How to get the probability data from survfit function?
I plot cumulative incidence curves based on data from the survival::survfit() function. Following this vignette I do something like the following:
library(survival)
mgus2$etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
mgus2$event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))
mfit2 <- survfit(Surv(etime, event) ~ sex, data=mgus2)
plot(mfit2)


The data has two possible events (pcm and death) and the included covariate sex has two levels (male and female). Thus, as expected, the resulting plot depicts the the probabilities for four lines (I left out the labels because they don't matter here).
But how to extract this data? I looked everywhere inside mfit2 but can not find the data needed to create the plot. There is mfit2$time for the x axis, but mfit2$pstate does not include all four probabilities (pcm female, pcm male, death female and death male). Where are those probabilities hidden in mfit2?
I found this answer which suggests some workaround in order to get the data. I see that the workaround works, that's not the question. Where is the data for the plot inside mfit2? It must be somewhere since plot(mfit2) returns as the plot we would expect.

Look at  mfit2$pstate

@Edward I did. It has only columns for death and pcm (and s0), but there is no grouping variable (ie no death male/ death female, ...). From question above: "mfit2$pstate does not include all four probabilities"

@Edward So the data stacked on top each other. How to know what rows correspond to what factor level of sex? I can solve it here but unsure for other use cases. Is it ordred by factor level order? Has every levels always same number of rows?

@Edward Returns a plot with six lines, not four.

"Has every levels always same number of rows?" - Not necessarily. You need to inspect the $strata object for that.

You're after the $pstate, which contains the concatenated probabilities for the two levels of sex (females are the first level).
levels(mgus$sex)
#[1] "female" "male" 

The length of mfit2$pstate (and mfits$time) is 454, the first 227 corresponds to probabilities for females (red).
mfit2$strata
sex=F sex=M 
  227   227

You can see that this is correct by plotting the fitted object and overlaying the lines based on the above information.
plot(mfit2)
lines(mfit2$time[1:227], mfit2$pstate[1:227, 2], type="s", col="red", lty=2)
lines(mfit2$time[228:454], mfit2$pstate[228:454, 2], type="s", col="green", lty=2)
lines(mfit2$time[1:227], mfit2$pstate[1:227, 3], type="s", col="red", lty=2)
lines(mfit2$time[228:454], mfit2$pstate[228:454, 3], type="s", col="green", lty=2)



Check my edit. You need to inspect the $strata object for the sample sizes. For this situation, the sizes are 249 and 202.

I found survminer which extracts the data and makes plots. But to me it is better to do it by my own in order to be able to make changes to the plot more easily. For example, I prefer different lines with colours and linetypes rather than areas and facets. What I did is:
# Load library
library(survival)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)


# Data
mgus2$etime <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, futime, ptime))
event <- with(mgus2, ifelse(pstat==0, 2*death, 1))
mgus2$event <- factor(event, 0:2, labels=c("censor", "pcm", "death"))
mgus2 <- within(mgus2, hgb_group <- hgb < mean(hgb, na.rm= TRUE))
mgus2 <- within(mgus2, age_group <- cut(age, quantile(age, 0:3/3)))
mfit2 <- survfit(Surv(etime, event) ~ sex + hgb_group, data=mgus2)

# Own function.
cuminc_plot <- function(fit){
  vars <- strsplit(as.character(fit$call[2]), "~")[[1]][2] %>%
    {strsplit(., "\\+")[[1]]} %>%
    trimws()
  df <- as.character(fit$call[3])
  states <- fit$states[-1]

  levels_order <- lapply(rev(vars), function(var_i){
    eval(parse(text= paste0("unique(sort(", df, "$", var_i, "))")))}) %>%
    do.call("expand.grid", .) %>%
    setNames(., nm= rev(vars))

  plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(time= fit$time,
                                fit$pstate[ , -1])

  plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(plot_data,
                                levels_order[rep(1:nrow(levels_order), times=     mfit2$strata), , drop= FALSE])

  plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols= states,
                        names_to= "state",
                        values_to= "p") 

  plot_obj <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(time, p, col= !!sym(vars[1]), linetype= state)) +
    geom_line()

  if(length(vars) == 2){
    plot_obj <- plot_obj +
      facet_wrap(as.formula(paste(". ~", vars[2]))) +
      scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name= vars[2], breaks = NULL, labels = NULL))

  } else if(length(vars) == 3){
    plot_obj <- plot_obj +
      facet_grid(as.formula(paste(vars[3], "~", vars[2]))) +
      scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name= vars[2], breaks = NULL, labels = NULL)) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name= vars[3], breaks = NULL, labels = NULL))
  }

  return(plot_obj)
}
cuminc_plot(mfit2)


Compare to source code from survminer (https://rdrr.io/cran/survminer/src/R/ggcompetingrisks.R)
ggcompetingrisks_lines <- function(fit){
  times <- fit$time
  psta <- as.data.frame(fit$pstate)
  colnames(psta) <- fit$states
  if (is.null(fit$strata)) {
    psta$strata <- "all"
  } else {
    psta$strata <- rep(names(fit$strata), fit$strata)
  }
  psta$times <- times

  .rename_empty_colname <- function(df, newname = "."){
    empty.col <- colnames(df) == ""
    empty.col.exist <- length(empty.col) > 0
    if(empty.col.exist)
      colnames(df)[empty.col] <- newname
    df
  }


  psta <- .rename_empty_colname(
    psta, newname = "."
  )

  event <- value <- strata <- NULL
  pstal <- tidyr::gather(psta, event, value, -strata, -times)

  #ggplot(pstal, aes(times, value, fill=event)) + geom_area() + facet_wrap(~strata)
  # instead:
  ggplot(pstal[pstal$event != "(s0)", ], aes(times, value, col=event)) +
    geom_line() + facet_wrap(~strata)
}

ggcompetingrisks_lines(mfit2)


But this gives facets instead of linetye and col. So adjusting my function:
cuminc_plot_fac <- function(fit){
  vars <- strsplit(as.character(mfit2$call[2]), "~")[[1]][2] %>%
    {strsplit(., "\\+")[[1]]} %>%
    trimws()
  df <- as.character(mfit2$call[3])
  states <- mfit2$states[-1]

  levels_order <- lapply(rev(vars), function(var_i){
    eval(parse(text= paste0("unique(sort(", df, "$", var_i, "))")))}) %>%
    do.call("expand.grid", .) %>%
    setNames(., nm= rev(vars))

  plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(time= mfit2$time,
                                mfit2$pstate[ , -1])

  plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(plot_data,
                                levels_order[rep(1:nrow(levels_order), times= mfit2$strata), , drop= FALSE])

  plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols= states,
                        names_to= "state",
                        values_to= "p") 

  plot_data$both <- paste0("sex=", plot_data$sex, ", ", "hgb_group=", plot_data$hgb_group)
  plot_obj <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(time, p, col= state)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(as.formula("~ both"))

  return(plot_obj)
}
cuminc_plot_fac(mfit2)


Finally, Trying to make a function that gives "same" plot as survminer, i.e. with areas and facets:
cuminc_plot_like_survminer <- function(fit){
  vars <- strsplit(as.character(mfit2$call[2]), "~")[[1]][2] %>%
    {strsplit(., "\\+")[[1]]} %>%
    trimws()
  df <- as.character(mfit2$call[3])
  states <- mfit2$states

  levels_order <- lapply(rev(vars), function(var_i){
    eval(parse(text= paste0("unique(sort(", df, "$", var_i, "))")))}) %>%
    do.call("expand.grid", .) %>%
    setNames(., nm= rev(vars))

  plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(time= mfit2$time,
                                mfit2$pstate)

  plot_data <- cbind.data.frame(plot_data,
                                levels_order[rep(1:nrow(levels_order), times= mfit2$strata), , drop= FALSE])

  plot_data <- plot_data %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols= states,
                        names_to= "state",
                        values_to= "p") 


  plot_data$both <- paste0("sex=", plot_data$sex, ", ", "hgb_group=", plot_data$hgb_group)
  plot_obj <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(time, p, fill= state)) +
    geom_area() +
    facet_wrap(as.formula("~ both"))


  return(plot_obj)
}
survminer::ggcompetingrisks(mfit2)
cuminc_plot_like_survminer(mfit2)

Plots are same in meaning (theme and so on are different but that does not matter).
